# SQL: Insert..ON DUPLICATE KEY isn't working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, insert

My query, in PHP, is:

```
$upd2 = $di->getDb()->prepare('INSERT INTO '. self::TABLE . '_agrupamento_avaliacao (idSemana, idEntidade_agrupamento) VALUES(?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE idEntidade_agrupamento=VALUES(idEntidade_agrupamento)');
$upd2->Execute(array($semana, $agrupamento));
```

But it isn't working. It's inserting the same data.
I tested querying:

`INSERT INTO entidade_agrupamento_avaliacao (idSemana, idEntidade_agrupamento) VALUES(17, 2808) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` `idEntidade_agrupamento=VALUES(idEntidade_agrupamento)`

But it also insert the same data instead of update the data.

My table is:

```
CREATE TABLE `entidade_agrupamento_avaliacao` (
`id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`idSemana` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`idEntidade_Agrupamento` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
INDEX `FK__semana` (`idSemana`),
INDEX `FK_entidade_agrupamento_avaliacao_entidade_agrupamento` (`idEntidade_Agrupamento`),
CONSTRAINT `FK__semana` FOREIGN KEY (`idSemana`) REFERENCES `semana` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT `FK_entidade_agrupamento_avaliacao_entidade_agrupamento` FOREIGN KEY (`idEntidade_Agrupamento`) REFERENCES `entidade_agrupamento` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
)COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=4
;
```

What is the problem?

Consider "$di->getDb()->prepare" as the PDO Statement prepare.

Comment: `AUTO_INCREMENT`. Simply `1,1,1` and `2,1,1` are different. There is no duplicate here.

Comment: That's strange, considering that I have another table here that the id is also 
 AUTO_INCREMENT and the update properly happens..

Comment: Do you explicitly insert `id` value?

Comment: Well..I think I just figured out the problem. Thanks! Your comment was helpful, lad2025!

Comment: In the other table that update happen, the fields are unique and what it's specified in the ON DUPLICATE KEY clause is the unique field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is your query:

```
INSERT INTO '. self::TABLE . '_agrupamento_avaliacao (idSemana, idEntidade_agrupamento)
    VALUES(?, ?)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE idEntidade_agrupamento = VALUES(idEntidade_agrupamento)');
```

The only unique index that you have on the table is the primary key on `id`.  This is auto-incremented, so it is not going to generate a duplicate.

Presumably, you want to declare `idSemana` as being unique.  Then the duplicate key can be caught.  You were probably thinking that `index idSemana` is sufficient for this purpose, but you really need `unique idSemana`.

Comment: @LeonardoSantos If it worked, then it would be good to mark the answer as accepted (with the "check" icon on the left, under the voting arrows), so that other users can benefit from this solution too.

Comment: I did it now. Sorry, haha..I had to left the computer before the system allows me to check his answer. Now I am back and just did.

Comment: @LeonardoSantos ;-)